# Is every well-defined map continuous? 

Tags: real-analysis

I am working on the function $f:[0,1) \to [0,1]$ defined by $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{x+1}$ for each $x\in [0,1)$.

It is clear that $f$ is well defined and continuous.

Now consider another function given by
$$
F(x)=
 \begin{cases}
 f(x), &x\in[0,1),
 \\ 1, & x = 1.
 \end{cases}
$$
It is clear that $F$ is an extension of $f$ into $[0,1]$. But it is not clear to me that $F$ is not continuous at $x=1$, even though it is defined at $x=1$.
Please I need more clarification about this.

Comment: Do you know any definition of continuity adequate for metric spaces? How is continuity at 1 related to $lim_{x \to 1}f(x)$?

Comment: What is $\lim_{x\to1}f(x)$?

Comment: @AD $\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: I don't understand the question *Does every well define map continuous?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, a function $g$ is *well-defined* at $a$ if $g(a)$ exists.

In general, a function $g$ is *continuous* at $a$ if:

- $g(a)$ exists, and
- $\lim\limits_{x\to a} g(x)$ exists, and
- $g(a) = \lim\limits_{x\to a}g(x)$.

Therefore, if a function $g$ is continuous at $a$, then it must be well-defined there.  However, the converse may not be true: a function may be well-defined at a point, but not continuous there.

For example, your function $F$ is well-defined at $x = 1$ (since $F(1)$ exists), but is not continuous at $x = 1$ (since $\lim\limits_{x \to 1}F(x) \neq F(1)$.)

On the other hand, note that while your function $f$ is well-defined and continuous on $[0,1)$, it is *not* well-defined at $x = 1$, and so it is not continuous at $x = 1$.

Comment: If I get you, every continuous function at a point $x_{0}$ is well define at that point, if the function is not well define at $x_{0}$ then it is not continuous there.

Comment: @HassanMuhammad: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I am misunderstanding something, but that function is clearly NOT continuous at $x=1$ just by definition of continuity: $F(1)=1$, but $\lim_{x\rightarrow1^-}F(x)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Which implies which? Well define or continuity?

Comment: @Hassan The function $f$ is well-defined, but not continuous. If the limit of f at 1 is well-defined depends on your definition of limit. So, what is the object whose well-definedness concerns you?

Comment: @Hassan: you should clarify yourself the meaning of *well-definedness* and *continuity*. Well-defined means that the function attains a particular value, without ambiguity - and this is true in your case. Continuity, assuming the Euclidean topology, means that the value $F(x_0)$ equals the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}F(x)$. So, your function is well-defined but not continuous at $x=1$.

Comment: @ValerioCapraro: I agree with you. Jesse solution make sense, and I think you are saying the same thing.

Comment: yes, we are saying the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

We may always extend $f$ to a well-defined function on $[0,1]$ - to do this we just have to say what $f(1)$ is.

Since $\lim_{x\to1}f(x)$ exists we may extend $f$ to a continuous function on $[0,1]$ - to do this we must set $f(1)= \lim_{x\to1}f(x)$.

Comment: This is a good exercise. Do you try proving?

Comment: @DanPetersen You are totally right! I removed that. :)

Answer (score 1):

As the variable $x$ tends to $1$, $F(x)$ tends to $1/2$, which is different from the value of $F$ at the point $1$. Intuitively, the graph of $F$ has more than one piece near the point 1, which is said to be discontinuous at the point $1$.

What should be noticed is that sometimes, even the graph has more than one piece near a point $x_{0}$, we still regard it a continuous function at  $x_{0}$ as long as $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x)=f(x_0)$. For example, the function

$G(x)=x \sin\frac{1}{x}$ for $x\neq 0, G(0)=0$

has three pieces near 0, but it's continuous at 0.

So the continuousness is just a description of the function having one piece near a point in the "limit" sense.